# What applications is NTFS preferable for?

Tags: ntfs

When building a new server I prefer to deploy Linux as my OS of choice. This gives me the luxury of being able to choose from various file systems (amongst other aspects), and I will choose a different FS for different servers, depending on what they will be used for.

With Windows OS variants you can only use NTFS. Have any benchmarks or tests been performed that have shown NTFS to be a preferable choice for a given scenario or application (apart from just "running Windows" because it has to be on NTFS).

To clarify what I mean; I might use filesystem X for large transactional storage volumes, but filesystem Y for front end web app servers. If I had a multi-platform application to deploy that (let's pretend) was available on Mac/Win/Lin, is there any type of application or scenario that would benefit from being on NTFS?

Comment: Is "Windows" an acceptable answer for preferable applications? :D  I'm kinda curious if anyone else has a different, useful answer, but my initial reaction is that NTFS, like any FS, is preferable for running the applications [OSes] that natively support it.

Comment: When you need to do full drive encryption with TPM

Comment: "We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion" Not really, I asked for bench marks and test results showing the benefits of using NTFS for "storage area networking" or "front end wep app servers" (as examples) which would be factual data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess in the same way that EXT* is most the standard format for most Linux installs, NTFS is for Windows. It supports file system level compression (although only really useful for logs and the like) and it is also the only file system that Windows supports in terms of file and folder security ACLs and VSS backup routines.

It does have support for very large volume and file sizes, larger than EXT3, and as of v3.1 has EFS encryption support.